# Can't read Google Pay Pass event card through another phone's NFC reader

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nfc, google-pay

I need to make an app that is able to read the Google Pay Pass event ticket through NFC. But I can't find any way how to deal with it. I saw some top apps in Google Play, as PassWallet and Passes, which works with such event tickets.

But they all could add a new ticket through scanning barcode only, not through NFC touch. I tried to open a ticket in Google Pay app and read it through another phone's NFC reader but didn't receive any information about the ticket, I always receive my default credit card info even when I open needed card.

So my question is that is it possible to read Google Pay Pass event ticket through another phone's NFC, as in the picture below?

[image]

If yes, could you share with me some example codes on how to do it?

Comment: You need to use Google Smart Tap for enable NFC on you Google Pay Passes. (https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/smart-tap/overview/about-smart-tap)

Note : PassWallet and Passes use Apple format (A file .pkpass).  (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1). But I do not recommend using them for NFC!

You have to sign a NDA with Google for use Google Smart Tap. There is a key exchange during the NFC transaction, the NFC payload is encrypted.

Comment: @xav-stargate thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

For a Google Pay issued pass the pass must be saved to [google pay](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/implementing-the-api/save-to-google-pay) on the mobile device and that passes class must be set to [enable smart tap](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/loyaltyclass#LoyaltyClass.FIELDS.enable_smart_tap) and the pass itself must have the `smartTapRedemptionValue` [field](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/loyaltyobject#LoyaltyObject.FIELDS.smart_tap_redemption_value) set as below:

```
{
 ...
 "smartTapRedemptionValue": "Value to Transmit",
 ...
}
```

The device acting as the terminal (reads the pass) must implement the [Smart Tap Protocol](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/smart-tap/overview/about-smart-tap) and present the collector id, and signed payload to the mobile device to authenticate the terminal and send passes that it can redeem.

The passes class also has the [field](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/loyaltyclass#LoyaltyClass.FIELDS.redemption_issuers) `redemptionIssuers` can specify which terminal's collector id can redeem it.

In order to implement [Smart Tap Protocol](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/smart-tap/overview/about-smart-tap) you can request access to the NDA protected docs via a [form](https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/contact/smart_tap_support?visit_id=636808476174432072-1655239078&rd=1) and that has the details on how to configure a device acting as a terminal to read passes.

There are also already certified supported terminal [providers](https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/answer/7394145?hl=en) available.